# How to use formValueSelector() of redux form to acces of the value of a button

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I use redux-from for create some form.

Today, i need to create a form that it's dynamic. 
More precisely, when the user click on a button some field are display.

I have found this sample on the [documentation of redux-form](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/selectingformvalues/).
In this sample, it is a checkbox.

I try to do the same thing with a button but it does not work.

Something to do for that works with a button ?

For me, it is the same logic that for a checkbox

```
<Field
  name="button"
  id="button"
  type='button'
  component={renderButton}
/>
{ button &&
   <div>
     test
   </div>
}


const selector = formValueSelector( 'testFrom' );

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    const button = selector( state , 'button' );
    return {
        button ,
    };
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button` element doesn't have `value` property, thats why `selector(state, 'button')` return nothing.

Add `onClick` handler to your button, where you can set any value to state of your form component. And depending on this value show or hide additional fields.

> [Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/m3pr9o1z1x)

```
class SelectingFormValuesForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isEmailVisible: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {handleSubmit} = this.props;
        const {isEmailVisible} = this.state;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                {isEmailVisible &&
                <Field
                    name="email"
                    component="input"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                />
                }
                <button type="button" onClick={this.onShowEmailFieldClick}>{isEmailVisible ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} email field</button>
            </form>
        );
    }

    onShowEmailFieldClick = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isEmailVisible: !prevState.isEmailVisible
        }));
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
That works but I try to create stateless an component so without have need to change the state.
Furthermore, in my case, I want the possibility to hide and delete the value of this field when the users click on this.
I try to dispatch an action of redux-from but it does not work.

Comment: if you need to have stateless component, you can pass onShowEmailFieldClick function and isEmailVisible value as props from parent component. To remove field toggle isEmailVisible value